# iOS7 homescreen app does not read AppCache manifest

Tags: ios7, html5-appcache

It seems that the iOS7 does not update our homescreen application even when there is an update available.

Forcing an update doesn't seem to change any state of the appcache in iOS7.

Is anyone expriencing the same, and has anyone found a solution?

Comment: I'm noticing this too. Even deleting the entry under Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data > <my.website.com> didn't work until I deleted the icon from the homescreen and "re-bookmarked" it.

Comment: I tried deleting all history, website data, reseting network, deleting the icon. Nothing work.